# Markov chain with dynamic higher orders

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $X_i$ be the node visited by a random walk at step $i$, and the following equations be the transition probabilities.

$Pr(X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1 = x_1)
= Pr(X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \cdots, X_{n-m} = x_{n-m}$),

where $x_i \in V = \{\text{the set of all nodes\}}$ and $1 \leq m < n$ is the order of the chain.

Then, assume that we have 3 nodes(A,B,C) and obtain the following sequence as a result of a random walk algorithm:

$A \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow  A \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow \cdots$

That is, after all three nodes are visited, a node in $V$ can be revisited. (In other words, the random walk uses a memory *until all three nodes are visited*). As shown in this sequence, it intuitively seems to have the positive recurrent property.

Finally, I would like to say that **the random walk has a limiting distribution** since it is a positive recurrent ***Markov chain***. However, the problem is that the random walk has dynamic higher orders, so that we cannot call it a Markov chain.

All the books or documents what I have studied are dealing with Markov chains with first order or *higher order that is fixed*, in order to say a limiting stationary distribution.

Is there any way to assert that the random walk above has a limiting distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the problem to a Markov chain problem by adding states:  Now you have states, $(A), (B),(C),(A,B),(A,C),(B,C),(A,B,C)$, and then just make sure that you only have the following non-zero-probability transitions:

$(A)\to (A,B)$

$(A)\to (A,C)$

$(B)\to (A,B)$

$(B)\to (B,C)$

$(C) \to (A,C)$

$(C) \to (B,C)$

$(A,B)\to (A,B,C)$

$(A,C) \to (A,B,C)$

$(B,C) \to (A,B,C)$

$(A,B,C)\to (A)$

$(A,B,C)\to (B)$

$(A,B,C)\to (C)$

For limiting distribution, you may want to make the additional states to be order-sensitive, for example $(A,B)$, $(B,A)$ are considered different states. In the end, the limiting distribution on the original $A,B,C$ states can be calculated from the limiting distribution on the enlarged set of states. For example, probability on $A$ will be the sum of probabilities on $(A),(B,A),(C,A),(B,C,A),(C,B,A)$